# Getting SQL Server Merge Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am trying to update the product history's average rating number by using the merge function

```
 MERGE ProductRankingHistory P
 USING Review R ON P.PRHProduct = R.ProductID

 WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE 
         SET P.PRHAverageRating = (SELECT AVG(ReviewRateValue) 
                                   FROM Review 
                                   WHERE ProductID = P.PRHProduct 
                                     AND YEAR(ReviewRateDate) = PRHYear);
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289612/msg-8672-level-16-state-1-line-1-the-merge-statement-attempted-to-update-or-d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Merge` seems unnecessary for this logic.  Something like:

```
UPDATE ProductRankingHistory P
    SET PRHAverageRating = (SELECT AVG(r.ReviewRateValue)
                            FROM Review r
                            WHERE r.ProductID = P.PRHProduct AND YEAR(r.ReviewRateDate) = P.PRHYear
                           )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Review r
                  WHERE r.ProductID = P.PRHProduct AND YEAR(r.ReviewRateDate) = P.PRHYear
                 );
```

After writing this, I see that you are probably using SQL Server (or a similar database).  The following might work:

```
UPDATE p
    SET PRHAverageRating = rp.avg_ReviewRateValue
    FROM ProductRankingHistory p JOIN
         (SELECT r.ProductID, YEAR(r.ReviewRateDate) as yyyy, AVG(r.ReviewRateValue) as avg_ReviewRateValue
          FROM Review r
          GROUP BY r.ProductID, YEAR(r.ReviewRateDate)
         ) rp
         ON rp.ProductId = p.PRHProduct AND rp.yyyy = p.prhYear;
```